# Multi selection in WPF Listview and multiple styles

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm

I have an application in WPF (MVVM).

- I've created a view model which points to an ObservableCollections to be shown in the ListView.
- The ListView has two custom view resources. 'GridView' and a 'TileView' and buttons to switch between them.

When I select multiple items and change to the other view the selected items are not sync...
after trying to debug I think that, for some reason, when changing views it:

1. Gets the IsSelected value for every Item in the list (That's OK)
2. Sets (again..) the Items that have just been set (in the other view..) (?)

The markup:

```
    <Window.Resources>

    <local:TileView x:Key="ImageView">
        <local:TileView.ItemTemplate >
            <DataTemplate >
                <StackPanel Width="150" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <Image Source="{Binding Path=ImagePath}"/>                        
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=PhotoReferenceCode}"/>                                                
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </local:TileView.ItemTemplate>
    </local:TileView>

    <GridView x:Key ="ListView">
        <GridViewColumn Header="Select" Width="100" >
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Width="100">
                        <!--<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>-->
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn>
        <GridViewColumn Header="Image" Width="100" >
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="{Binding Path=ImagePath}" Stretch="UniformToFill" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn>
        <GridViewColumn Header="Reference Code" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=PhotoReferenceCode}"/>
    </GridView>

</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ListView Margin="0,36,0,0"  View="{Binding  Path=ViewType, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" SelectionMode="Multiple" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding  Path=InfoList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>


    </ListView>
    <Button Name="btnListView" Content="ListView" Click="btnListView_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,9,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    <Button Name="btnImageView" Content="ImageView" Click="btnImageView_Click"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="99,9,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
</Grid>
```

The Item class:

```
public class ItemData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    #region Members

    private bool _IsSelected;

    public string ImagePath { get; set; }

    public string PhotoReferenceCode { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Constractors

    public ItemData()
    {

    }

    public ItemData(bool Is_Sected, string Image_Path, int Item_Carat, string Photo_Reference_Code)
    {
        IsSelected = Is_Sected;
        ImagePath = Image_Path;
        ItemCarat = Item_Carat;
        PhotoReferenceCode = Photo_Reference_Code;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Public

    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _IsSelected; }
        set
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null && _IsSelected != value)
            {
                _IsSelected = value; OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Events

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Bind all of the listview's SelectedItems to a property in the view model using TwoWay bind. So the viewModel keeps the selectedItems of the listview and so when the view is changed, the new listview style can pick up the selectedItems from the viewModel

Comment: `<ListView Margin="0,36,0,0"  View="{Binding  Path=ViewType, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" SelectionMode="Multiple" ItemsSource="{Binding  Path=InfoList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" 
SelectedItem="{Binding  Path=ViewType, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Mode=TwoWay}">`

Unfortunately no successes...

Comment: In your code why both view and selectedItems bind to the same Property "ViewType"??  View="{Binding  Path=ViewType, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"             SelectedItem="{Binding  Path=ViewType, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Mode=TwoWay}">

Comment: Declare a new property name and bind all your ListView's SelectedItem to that property in XAML.

Comment: ok Fine, What is the type of the "InfoList". paste the code of this property here.

Comment: OK Obviously what I've done has no sense.. (I'm new to .net and wpf, it's my second week...)
I'm not sure I understand what your saying...
(Just to be clear, I only have 1 listview with 2 views.)
So, I declared a new property named SelectedItem
`public ItemData SelectedItem
 {
    get { return _SelectedItem; }
    set{_SelectedItem = value; OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");}
 }`
and have bind it to the SelctedItem property in the ListView but it only takes one item...
`SelectedItem="{Binding  Path=SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"`

Comment: The type is an ObservableCollections of "ItemData"s as shown above

Comment: use ObservableCollection < ItemData> as your type instead of ItemData. let me know whether this works

Comment: This is what I'm using

Comment: Here you are using "public ItemData SelectedItem get { return _SelectedItem; }     set{_SelectedItem = value; OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");}  }", but I want to you to use public "ObservableCollection < ItemData> SelectedItem"

Comment: `public ObservableCollection<ItemData> InfoList
        {
            get { return _InfoList; }
            set { _InfoList = value; }
        }`

Comment: Change the SelectedItem property type to observablecollection< ItemData>

Comment: can you select multiple items??

Comment: Did you bind the selectedItems for both the views?

Comment: I bind it to the listview. the views don't have a SelectedItem property. they are just view resources for the view property of the lisview. there is no problem selecting multiple items. when the SelectedItem type was ItemData it would let me select multiple items but would only set at the first selection. now it only sets after all items selected are deselected and, in both cases, this behavior has nothing to do with the view change...

Comment: do you understand this behavior?